# Calculate the discrete probability of x number of good outcomes occurring before y number of bad outcomes

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, st.statistics

I have a grid of 16 tiles face down. Half are good outcomes and half are bad outcomes. How would I calculate the probability of picking x number of Good outcomes before y number of bad outcomes are picked.

Once a tile is selected and it’s state is revealed (good or bad), it is left face up. That is to say there are no replacements. Also order dose matter because the x number of good outcomes must be picked before the y number of bad outcomes.

Comment: This is a special case of the more general urn *problems*.  For $x\leq n\leq x+y-1$, the probability of having  flipped $x$ good tiles in $n$ flips is $$p_n=\frac{\Big(\prod_{k=0}^{x-1}(8-k)\Big)\Big(\prod_{j=0}^{n-x-1}(8-j)\Big)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(16-i)}\binom{n}{x}.$$ You areb looking at $p_x+p_{x+1}+\cdots +p_{x+y-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $x$ *good* before $y$ *bad* if you get $x$ or more *good* out of $x+y-1$ attempts.  Let's call the probability of this $P(x,y)$ and using hypergeometric probabilities we have $$P(x,y)= \sum_{n=x}^8 \frac{{8 \choose n}{8 \choose y-1}}{{16 \choose n+y-1}}$$

There are some fairly obvious symmetric and anti-symmetric shortcuts using combinatorial arguments:

- $P(x,x)= \frac12$ since *good* and *bad* are equally likely
- $P(x,y)= 1 - P(9-x,9-y)$ if we arrange all $16$ and count from the other end
- $P(x,y)= P(9-y,9-x)$ counting from the other end and swapping *good* and *bad*
- $P(x,y)= 1 - P(y,x)$ since one must come before the other swapping *good* and *bad*

Here is a table of the values of $P(x,y)$

$$\begin{matrix} 
{P}&x: &\mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{8} \\
y: \\
\mathbf{1} && \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac{ 7 }{ 30 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 10 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 26 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 78 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 1430 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 12870 }  \\
\mathbf{2} &&  \frac{ 23 }{ 30 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac{ 37 }{ 130 }  & \frac{ 11 }{ 78 }  & \frac{ 17 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 29 }{ 1430 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 198 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 1430 }  \\
\mathbf{3} &&  \frac{ 9 }{ 10 }  & \frac{ 93 }{ 130 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac{ 87 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 45 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 283 }{ 4290 }  & \frac{ 29 }{ 1430 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 286 }  \\
\mathbf{4} &&  \frac{ 25 }{ 26 }  & \frac{ 67 }{ 78 }  & \frac{ 199 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac{ 797 }{ 2574 }  & \frac{ 45 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 17 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 78 }  \\
\mathbf{5} &&  \frac{ 77 }{ 78 }  & \frac{ 269 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 241 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 1777 }{ 2574 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac{ 87 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 11 }{ 78 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 26 }  \\
\mathbf{6} &&  \frac{ 285 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 1401 }{ 1430 }  & \frac{ 4007 }{ 4290 }  & \frac{ 241 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 199 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac{ 37 }{ 130 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 10 }  \\
\mathbf{7} &&  \frac{ 1429 }{ 1430 }  & \frac{ 197 }{ 198 }  & \frac{ 1401 }{ 1430 }  & \frac{ 269 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 67 }{ 78 }  & \frac{ 93 }{ 130 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac{ 7 }{ 30 }  \\
\mathbf{8} &&  \frac{ 12869 }{ 12870 }  & \frac{ 1429 }{ 1430 }  & \frac{ 285 }{ 286 }  & \frac{ 77 }{ 78 }  & \frac{ 25 }{ 26 }  & \frac{ 9 }{ 10 }  & \frac{ 23 }{ 30 }  & \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } 
 \end{matrix}$$

The fractions could easily be given a common denominator of ${16 \choose 8}=12870$

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is very helpful! How would the formula change if there Wes not just good and bad but also neutral outcomes. The same question remains as picking x good before y bad, but now there are good, bad, and neutral tiles that make up the 16.

Comment: @user15156281 Any number of neutral tiles make no difference to the probabilities  of $x$ good before $y$ bad, they just add to the expected time before the end of the game

Comment: That makes sense. I really appreciate you helping me out on this!